# Understanding why a string stored in a linked list won't print properly

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, g++

I'm working on an assignment where I've been given specific member functions I need to complete for a linked-list. One of them requires me to copy a node, change its name, delete the old node and reinsert the new one back into the list. I've come up with this code

```
while(start != NULL)
{
    if(start->id == nID) 
    {
        start->name = newName;
        holdNode = start;
        removeNode(nID); //removes start from the linkedlist
        addNode(holdNode->name, holdNode->id, holdNode->cost); 

        found = true; 
        break;
    }
    else
        start = start->next;
```

I get the correct output in xcode, but when I run it with g++ the name field is either empty or a series of random characters. I'm guessing it has something to do with pointing to the start node and then deleting it, but I can't figure out why it will work in one place but not the other.

Xcode Output

```
1, testing, $9.99
```

g++

```
1, , $9.99
```

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: "*requires me to copy a node, change its name, delete the old node and reinsert the new one back into the list.*" - why does it need you to remove the old node? Your code is not making any copy, it just changes the name of the existing node that it finds, then it tries to remove that node, invalidating the pointer to the node, so you can't use that same pointer to reinsert a node afterwards. That is where your code is failing. Perhaps the requirement is to remove the found node and insert a NEW node with the new name? It doesn't make sense for a function named `changeName()` to remove anything

Comment: the linked list needs to be in alphabetical order and she doesn't want us to re sort it after a name change. The old node needs to be deleted and then the new one placed based on its new name.

Comment: Then the code you have shown is not implemented correctly for that task

Comment: I guess that's what i need help with now. How do I properly do this? Your suggestion to remove the old node and then insert a new one makes sense. I will try that.

Comment: Hi there--Stack Overflow questions are designed to be useful to future visitors. Removing code or any other significant portion of a question due to your classmates' behavior or any other reason significantly invalidates the question's usefulness, as well as that of its answers. For the time being I've rolled back your last edit. If you have concerns about your code being copied, edit it down to a minimal [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) representation of the issue you're facing, so that it's not as useful for plagiarism.

Comment: I reedited it down. Thank you.

Comment: This looks perfect. Thank you for taking the time to make the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not making any copy of a node. It merely updates the `name` of the existing node that it finds, then it saves a *pointer* to that node, removes that node from the list **invalidating the pointer you just saved**, then tries to use that *invalid pointer* to get the values to use when inserting a new node. That is where your code is failing.

Try this instead:

```cpp
bool changeName(int nID, string newName)
{
    Product *node = head;

    while (node) //while there are items in the list
    {
        if (node->id == nID) //if ids match
        {
            double price = node->price;
            removeNode(nID); //remove node from the linkedlist
            addNode(newName, nID, price); //insert new node
            return true;
        }

        node = node->next; //move to next node
    }

    return false;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/W6tfqv)

However, this is a little inefficient, as `removeNode()` is likely doing the same `id` search all over again.  A linked list is able to insert and remove a node *quickly*, without traversing the list multiple times.  Just unlink the found node from its surrounding nodes.  At the very least, you can get rid of the call to `removeNode()` in `changeName()` like this:

```cpp
bool changeName(int nID, string newName)
{
    Product *node = head, *prev = NULL;

    while (node) //while there are items in the list
    {
        if (node->id == nID) //if ids match
        {
            double price = node->price;

            //remove node from the linkedlist
            //removeNode(nID);
            if (prev) prev->next = node->next;
            if (node == head) head = node->next;
            delete node;

            //insert new node
            addNode(newName, nID, price);

            return true; 
        }

        prev = node;
        node = node->next; //move to next node
    }

    return false;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/nm3bms)

Another option would be to not actually destroy the found node at all, simply relocate it as-is.  Unlink it from its surrounding nodes, and then link it to the nodes at the desired new position, eg:

```cpp
bool changeName(int nID, string newName)
{
    Product *node = head, *prev = NULL;

    while (node) //while there are items in the list
    {
        if (node->id == nID) //if ids match
        {
            //remove node from the linkedlist
            if (prev) prev->next = node->next;
            if (node == head) head = node->next;

            //insert node in new position
            Product **node2 = &head;
            while ((*node2) && ((*node2)->name < newName)) {
                node2 = &((*node2)->next);
            }

            node->name = newName;
            node->next = *node2;
            *node2 = node;

            return true; 
        }

        prev = node;
        node = node->next; //move to next node
    }

    return false;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/sAQPuA)